# If I swallow you, you'll die

Tags: riddle

> If you swallow me, you'll live,
>
> but if I swallow you, you'll die.

What am I?

Reason [why](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323397/if-i-swallow-part-of-an-animal-am-i-not-entitled-to-say-i-swallowed-an-animal/323401#323401) it can't be an animal

Comment: I think this is too broad. As suggested below, many animals will fit these 2 clues.

Comment: I think people have a misconception

Comment: If you swallow an animal you must have a large mouth

Comment: If I swallow part of an animal, am I not entitled to say "I swallowed an animal"?

Comment: No, because you didn't swallow the entire animal.

Comment: I meant 'an animal in parts', but never mind. Somehow this reminds me of a friend who once said: "100% of people who eat cheese die"

Comment: That isn't a valid argument. If you were going to meant "an animal in parts" how can that same "part" swallow you?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323397/if-i-swallow-part-of-an-animal-am-i-not-entitled-to-say-i-swallowed-an-animal/323401#323401

Comment: Ok, what about a piranha, it can swallow you, and you can swallow it

Comment: Keep in mind, water swallowing you is probably equally as abstract as an animal swallowing you, in part or in whole. There is still some sort of "metaphorical" extension.

Comment: Insects are animals.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Water

Because ..

> Drink water and you live. Drown in it and you don't.

Comment: What that's too fast

Comment: @UserBlanko It's almost the first thing that'll come to anyone's mind.

Answer (score 17):

Another alternative solution:

> A bitter truth

Because:

> If you can swallow it, you can move on in life.  If you let the bitterness consume you, you could die of heart attack or hypertension.

Comment: Creative thinking... +1

Answer (score 10):

I think that the answer is:

> Pacman

because:

> If he swallows the Ghosts, he lives. But if they swallow him, he dies.

Comment: That is also a creative answer!

Comment: nice! i dint think of it that way

Comment: Wouldn't the answer be "ghosts" then?

Answer (score 7):

> Pride

because:

> If you swallow your pride, you'll live.
>  But if you let pride swallow you, "pride goeth before destruction, a haughty spirit before a fall".

Answer (score 4):

Alternate solution

> A vicious dog (or any suitable animal)

Because

> You can swallow an animal if you cut it up, but if it swallows (eats) you, game over.